# Not able to disconnect when manual press if i turn of and on the bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect

I am facing a problem while disconnecting a ble device.

I have an android application that talks to ble device, I connect to the GATT with the auto connect enabled, Now I have a button on which I am disconnecting the device and then closing GATT.

The disconnect is working fine when I normally go into the application, turn on my Bluetooth and then connect to the device.

But once the device is connected if I turn my phones Bluetooth of and then turn it on(I am calling a broadcast receiver when Bluetooth turned on or of), i am reconnecting to the previous device is auto-connect on. But this time if I try to disconnect it, does not disconnect the device.

Comment: you should try disconnecting device in your broadcast receiver for Bluetooth Off

Comment: I am doing that, but once the bluetooth is turned on i am again connecting to the previous connected device. But this time if i press disconnect it is not disconnecting. If i close the application connect again then disconnect is working fine.

Comment: share your full code

Comment: Maybe you call disconnect / close on the old BluetoothGatt object instead of the new?

Comment: I am using the same object to connect when disconnected and Bluetooth turned on.